# CSS: How do I scale an element at a steady speed using cubic-bezier?

Tags: css, css-animations, scale, cubic-bezier

I have a `16384px X 16384px` canvas.
I start off with my canvas scaled down to `512px`.
I then scale my canvas to its original size.

The scaling (in and out) works.

The problem is that even though I've set the timing function to `linear` it doesn't look "linear". It speeds up at the start and slows down at the end.

You can see what I'm describing here:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
let button = document.querySelector('button')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

button.onclick = function() {
    if (canvas.classList.contains('scale')) {
        canvas.classList.remove('scale')
    } else {
    canvas.classList.add('scale')
  }
}

let img = new Image()
img.height = '256px'
img.width = '256px'

img.onload = function() {
  let y = 0
  while (y < 16384) {
    let x = 0
    while (x < 16384) {
      ctx.drawImage(img, x, y)
      x+=256
    }
    y+=256
  }
  
  button.classList.remove('hidden')
}

img.src = 'https://i.etsystatic.com/16276846/r/il/ab3661/1503703028/il_570xN.1503703028_frl8.jpg'
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(0.03125, 0.03125, 0.03125);
  transition: transform 5s linear;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

canvas.scale {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="16384px" height="16384px"></canvas>
<button class="hidden">
scale
</button>
```

I understand that this is a known "problem" related to the size of the element being scaled (in my case it's pretty huge) and (I assume) the duration (?) of the scaling (in my case it's 5 seconds).

I know that the "solution" is to use a `cubic-bezier()` timing function but I don't know what values to use in order to create a steady (as much as possible) scaling in (and out) animation.

Is there some "formula" to figure out the values `cubic-bezier()` should have in *my* context ?

Maybe what I'm describing as a "problem" is actually an optical illusion (that things are speeding up or slowing down even though this never actually happens) that you cannot prevent when scaling (?)

**Note:** I don't mind increasing the duration of the transition from 5s to whatever (<=10s) is needed in order to create a steady scale in/out.

Comment: Maybe the speed is something about the size and the hardware struggling to scale it properly, because linear should do the trick: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition_speed. Can you add a working example with the snippet tool (or a fiddle)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try creating a jsFiddle.

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Devtools allows you to edit timing functions and suggests "quadratic" as one on the function sets
This example uses "quadratic in" and "quadratic out"

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
let button = document.querySelector('button')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

button.onclick = function() {
    if (canvas.classList.contains('scale')) {
        canvas.classList.remove('scale')
    } else {
    canvas.classList.add('scale')
  }
}

let img = new Image()
img.height = '256px'
img.width = '256px'

img.onload = function() {
  let y = 0
  while (y < 16384) {
    let x = 0
    while (x < 16384) {
      ctx.drawImage(img, x, y)
      x+=256
    }
    y+=256
  }
  
  button.classList.remove('hidden')
}

img.src = 'https://i.etsystatic.com/16276846/r/il/ab3661/1503703028/il_570xN.1503703028_frl8.jpg'
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(0.03125, 0.03125, 0.03125);
  transition: transform 5s linear;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

canvas.scale {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  
  
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.09, 0.68, 0.53);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="16384px" height="16384px"></canvas>
<button class="hidden">
scale
</button>
```